# Show and hide elements based on their [title] using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I am trying to create a list of items which, when you click on one, opens the video related to that item. So I tried to work with [title] so that whenever I click one one item with title=xxx the video with title=xxx will show (and the others will hide). I cannot figure how to use the variable to select the correct item. Here's what I tried:

```js
$(".speaker").click(function() {
  let speakerName = $(this).attr('title');
  console.log(speakerName);
  $(".speaker-content [title!=" + speakerName + "]").hide();
  $(".speaker-content [title ==" + speakerName + "]").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="presentations">
  <div class="speaker" title="s5-sp1">
    <p><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>Dr Daniel</p>
  </div>

  <div class="speaker-content" title="s5-sp1">
    <div class="videowrapper">
      <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/xxx" title="YouTube video player"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I also tried to go through them with a for each but with no success

Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: get rid of the space in `".speaker-content[title...`. As written, it's looking for at thing with the title attribute as a child of speaker content.

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem !! Have a great evening kind man :))

Comment: Please don't edit your question to show the code with the solution applied; that won't help people looking for the answer.  Instead, if you want to answer the question yourself, add an Answer to the question. Or, you could accept an existing answer. Either way, there's no need to edit the title or the question when it is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest error was the space between the class and the attribute. The attribute is on the same class so they need to be connected. Also, you don't use the comparative operator `==` inside an attribute.

```
$('.speaker').click(function(){
  let speakerName = $(this).attr('title');
  $('.speaker-content').hide();
  $(`.speaker-content[title='${speakerName}']`).show();
});
```

Comment: Yes the "==" was acutally an edit I made after posting, I feel so dumb. I'll change it so I don't confuse potential readers in the future.

Thank you so much for the help it solved everything !

Comment: @Dendenzilla  - glad it helped. When you get a moment, please accept this as the solution by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer. Cheers!

Comment: @Kinglish is correct - if an answer solved it for you, accept it.